# Rails 4 - All Tests Failing (even Assert true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

New to rails and just getting started learning testing. We're having a problem that probably has a simple answer that has us stumped.

We have wrote some code and got it working in development (just static code and a login system w/ Devise). The only test cases in our file were generated by rails, for example:

```
  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
  end
```

However, when we run `bundle exec rake test`, to our surprise, we **fail every single test**.

```
10 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 10 errors, 0 skips
```

Each test has the same error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (980190962, null, 2015-10-27 09:40:30, 2015-10-27 09:40:30).
: INSERT INTO "leads" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2015-10-27 09:40:30', '2015-10-27 09:40:30', 980190962)
```

By reading that error, it seems like there is some record in our `leads` table without an email. E-mail was a field created later after a migration. However, looking through psqlAdmin, every row has an e-mail. Furthermore, if we look in the console after loading the pages in chrome, there are no errors.

Even the most basic test is failing with the same error:

```
test "the truth" do
    assert true
end
```

My only guess is that there is some default seeding going on, and it is trying to insert a field into leads without an e-mail. However, `seeds.rb` is completely blank.

Here is the start of my call in terminal:

```
Macintosh-2:triplanding Calvino$ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 15348

# Running:

EEEEEEEEEE

Finished in 0.108843s, 91.8753 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
```

1. Why are these tests failing?
2. Why is the `leads` even involved in a test like assert true.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

Here is my fixture/leads.yml file. We did not edit it, this is what was generated:

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
#  column: value
```

Comment: The default behavior for MiniTest is to use *fixtures*, not seeds. Can you edit your question to include the contents of `/test/fixtures/leads.yml`?

Comment: @LannyBose - updated with the fixtures file - though we also didn't touch that.

Comment: Yeah, so those get generated by default. Rails tries to create new records into a new, test database with that data. I'm wondering if either deleting those records or providing an email for those records will solve the problem in the short term.

Comment: See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Comment: @LannyBose - Commenting out those lines fixed the problem. Thank you for the resource!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moste likely it is because your fixtures cannot run due to:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
```

Check that none of your fixtures for leads contains a null email and it should probably work!

Whenever you run tests on rails it will setup the test-database (this is the reason even `assert true` fails)