# Rails 4 Integration Testing - Failing (event Assert True)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing, minitest

Alright, a little embarrassed I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364748/rails-4-all-tests-failing-even-assert-true/33364864) yesterday, but we're stuck again.

We've fixed all of our controller tests, and started writing integration tests. We're encountering errors on all of our integration tests, even the famous assert = true:

**site_layout_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest


  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

#commenting out our real tests for debugging

=begin
  test "top navigation bar links" do
    get 'beta/index'
    assert_template 'beta/index'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", home_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", how_it_works_path
    to do add map, community, sign up, login paths
    to do: add paths to links on dropdown if user is logged in
  end
=end

end
```

**Terminal Test Results**

```
12:31:32 - INFO - Running: test/integration/site_layout_test.rb
Started with run options --seed 27747

ERROR["test_the_truth", SiteLayoutTest, 2015-10-25 11:36:28 +0800]
 test_the_truth#SiteLayoutTest (1445744188.33s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass


  1/1: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.05380s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  include Devise::TestHelpers
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  #

  def setup_variables
    @base_title = "TripHappy"
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, that error message gives us very little clue as to where the error is occurring. I tried reading up on Minitests, but without an idea of where to look I'm fairly lost.

Thank you in advanced!

For reference, we're following [M. Harti's Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/), which means we're using Guard and Minitest Reporters. We also have a login system via Devise, if that affects anything.

**Solution:**

It was an issue with the Devise. I included `include Devise::TestHelpers` in `class ActiveSupport::TestCase` instead of `class ActionController::TestCase`.

Comment: I have a strong dislike for chains of questions, especially on virtually identical topics. They show very little progress being made without someone feeding you answers.

Comment: Please consider posting your solutions as an answer and accepting them, instead of editing them into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the Devise. I included include Devise::TestHelpers in class ActiveSupport::TestCase instead of class ActionController::TestCase